# group MYSQL rows by datetime buckets starting at specific datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have several columns, one of which has the datetimes below:

```
2015-07-19 17:00:01
2015-07-19 17:15:01
2015-07-19 17:30:01
2015-07-19 17:45:01
2015-07-19 18:00:01
2015-07-19 18:15:01
2015-07-19 18:30:01
2015-07-19 18:45:01
2015-07-19 19:00:01
2015-07-19 19:15:01
2015-07-19 19:30:01
2015-07-19 19:45:01
2015-07-19 20:00:01
2015-07-19 20:15:01
```

I want the output to cycle every 3 hours for aggregation purposes:

```
2015-07-19 17:00:01, max(column B), etc
2015-07-19 20:00:01, max(column B), etc
2015-07-19 23:00:01, max(column B), etc
2015-07-20 02:00:01, max(column B), etc
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT
datetime_col,
min(col_b)
FROM table
where datetime_col >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-07-19 17:00:01','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
GROUP BY
YEAR(datetime_col),
MONTH(datetime_col),
DAY(datetime_col),
ROUND(HOUR(datetime_col)/3);
```

Actual output:

```
2015-07-19 17:00:01
2015-07-19 20:00:01
2015-07-19 23:00:01
2015-07-20 00:00:01
2015-07-20 02:00:01
```

You can see that at first the grouping looks good until it reaches a new day. I need to group it on a 3 hour cycle regardless of day, month, year, etc.

Preferably I want to do this in a single query since I call it in a C# application;

Comment: How about `GROUP BY floor(unix_timestamp(datetime_col)/(3*3600))` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is create a table with ranges for dates and hours.

Here is an example with day, you will need expand with hours.

[generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

So you will have your `hour_block` table

```
id   startTime            endTime
 1   2015-07-19 00:00:01  2015-07-19 03:00:00
 2   2015-07-19 03:00:01  2015-07-19 06:00:00
 3   2015-07-19 06:00:01  2015-07-19 09:00:00
 ...         ...                ...
 8   2015-07-19 21:00:01  2015-07-20 00:00:00
```

Then you create a join

```
 SELECT H.id, H.startTime, max(Y.column B)
 From YourTable Y
 JOIN hour_block H
   ON Y.datetime_col between H.startTime and H.endTime
 GROUP BY H.id, H.startTime
```

Comment: JOIN-ing on range conditions can't use indexes.

Comment: @Vatev Can you share some documentation to describe that fact?

Comment: Facts don't need documentation :) In this case it's actually worse than the range condition problem, because the join uses 2 different columns and even if it were possible to join on a range it will only one of them (which in this case is as bad as no index).

Comment: @Vatev Yes, they need one, If you dont provide a proof is just an hypothesis.

Comment: Think of it as a warning. Anyone who decides to use this should check the query plan and consider the performance impact. My goal is not to prove you wrong or anything of that sort.

Comment: @Vatev thanks for your comment I will try do some test on my own for this case and let you know.

Comment: @Vatev Check this sample [**SqlFidle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58318/7) execution plan and how is using the index for range vs same table without index.

Comment: [type=index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index) means it is scanning the entire index, not using it for searching. Which is pretty much the same as scanning the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by converting the value to the nearest previous 3-hour period.  This is easy enough using `to_seconds()`, but the conversion back isn't allowed.  So:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimecol) / (60 * 60 / 3) )) as datetime,
      min(col_b)
FROM table
WHERE datetime_col >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-07-19 17:00:01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimecol) / (60 * 60 / 3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the 3 hours interval

```
CREATE TABLE T
(dcol datetime,b INT);

INSERT INTO t
VALUES('2015-07-19 17:00:01',23),
('2015-07-19 18:30:01',25),
('2015-07-19 19:00:01',66),
('2015-07-19 20:00:01',99),
('2015-07-19 21:00:01',5),
('2015-07-19 23:00:01',2),
('2015-07-20 02:00:01',78),
('2015-07-20 03:00:01',9),
('2015-07-20 05:00:01',11),
('2015-07-20 07:00:01',29)

SELECT t.dcol,t.b
FROM t JOIN t tt WHERE t.dcol=tt.dcol+INTERVAL 3 HOUR
UNION
SELECT tt.dcol,tt.b
FROM t JOIN t tt WHERE t.dcol=tt.dcol+INTERVAL 3 HOUR
ORDER BY dcol

dcol                 b
2015-07-19 17:00:01  23
2015-07-19 20:00:01  99
2015-07-19 23:00:01  2
2015-07-20 02:00:01  78
2015-07-20 05:00:01  11
```

Comment: This will not work. I need to group by so I can do some aggregation of the values within the 3 hour block